# How to prove that $F(x) = \int_0^x f(t)$ is differentiable at $0$. Here $f(t)$ is continuous on $[-2 , 2]$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives, solution-verification

How to prove that $F(x) = \int_0^x f(t)$  is differentiable at $0$.  Here $f(t)$ is continuous on $[-2 , 2]$.

**My Attempt :** For a positive number $e$ , we will get a $\delta > 0$  such that $ -e < f(t) - f(0) < e$ for all $t \in (-\delta , \delta).$

Now $\int_0^h (-e) < \int_0^h (f(t) - f(0)) < \int_0^h e \implies   -e < \frac{F(h) - F(0)}{h} - f(0)<  e $ for all $h \in (0 , \delta). $

So we can say $F_+'(0) = f(0)$

Now $\int_0^h (e) < \int_0^h (f(t) - f(0)) < \int_0^h -e \implies   -e < \frac{F(h) - F(0)}{h} - f(0) <  e $ for all $h \in (- \delta , 0). $

So we can say $F_-'(0) = f(0)$

$\therefore$  $F'(0) = f(0)$

Can anyone please check my attempt?

Comment: In second line integration $f(0)$ doesn't give $f(0)h$?

Comment: Thanking you for pointing out the mistake. I have edited. Please have a look.

Comment: Hmm,it seems ok. Why don't you see the proof of Fundamental theorem of calculus ?

Comment: For me it seems good now. Classical proofs of this theorem mainly use modulus in estimations directly, but it is same as you did.

Comment: Will it remain okay if I say the function is continuous at $0$ only?@zkutch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct, but you only need continuity at $0$ for this to hold.

This statement is a special case of the "Fundamental theorem of calculus".